# integrate over a contour

Tags: analysis

Please help me with this:

Find the value of  $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{z-Logz}dz$, $\gamma$ is the positively oriented contour consisting of four vertices at $2, 4, 4+3i, 2+3i$

Comment: How many solutions of $z = \operatorname{Log} z$ are inside the rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The function is holomorphic inside the region. Knowing this, is there any theorems you could use?